# Aplicativo não consegue acessar URL via Ajax quando está no android

Tags: ajax, phonegap-buillder

Estou tentando aprender o uso do Phonegap Build. Desenvolvi um pequeno aplicativo com um simples botão, que quando clicado, executará a função ajax do jquery. Essa função chamará uma URL externa e retornará sucess ou error, em caso de falha.
Quando o projeto está na minha máquina, ele acessa normal essa URL externa. Mas quando subo para o Phonegaph build, crio o aplicativo mobile e instalo no Android, dai não funciona. Clico no botão e ele retorna error, indicado que não conseguiu se conectar à URL externa usando o Ajax. Mas na minha máquina ele acessa.
Já encontrei no google inúmeras dicas pra colocar no config.xml, mas até agora nada resolveu.
Se alguém já criou alguma coisa com Phonegap Build que consiga acessar uma URL externa, e puder me dar alguma sugestão, agradeço.

Comment: Coloque o código, por favor, e a saída de erros.

Comment: A página HTML: http://pastebin.com/R0SvDf03
Meu arquivo config.xml atual: http://pastebin.com/KsVc8Dsh

Comment: Pablo, perceba que meu código é simples. Apenas uma função ajax que chama uma URL. Como eu disse, funciona no PC, mas depois que transformo em aplicativo android, retorna "error".